# Schrödinger equation: well-posedness with Hartree potential and Yukawa potential

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the Schrödinger equation of Hartree type (HT):

$$i\partial_tu +\Delta u + (V\ast |u|^2)u=0, u(x,0)=u_0$$
with $(x,t)\in \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R.$
where $V$ is some potential.

(1) when $V(x)= |x|^{-\gamma} , 0<\gamma<d$ ( Hartree potential)
(2) when $V(x)=e^{-|x|}|x|^{-\gamma} , 0<\gamma<d$ (Yukawa potential)

There  are papers in the literature with  Hartree potential and Yukawa potential.

> My question is: How the well-posedness results of (HT)  with Hartree potential and Yukawa potential differs?  Is there any special reasons,  the two different potential has been considered?

My Thought: (1)It seems, if we have well-posedness results for (HT) with  Hartree potential, we will most probably  have the well poshness results for  (HT) with Yukawa potential. (2) I do not know many papers on (HT) with Yukawa potential, any good reference?